# Optimizing interpolation Python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to design function that will convert image from cartesian to polar coordinates. To do that I need to use interpolation, but my code runs extremely slow, the bottleneck is the following function:

```
def img2polar(img, center, final_radius, angle_resolution, Xcart, Ycart):

    points = list(itertools.product(np.arange(0.5, img.shape[0]+0.5, 1.), np.arange(0.5, img.shape[1]+0.5, 1.)))

    values = np.reshape(img, img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 'C')

    f = interpolate.griddata(points, values, (Xcart, Ycart), method='linear')

    return f
```

Is there any way to accelerate it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well... ```method=nearest``` should be faster at some costs (precision), but the question is, if ```interpolate.griddata``` is the right tool to use? It seems very general and should suffer from this generality. What about ```NearestNDInterpolator```, ```interp2d``` or ```interpn```?

Comment: typically, how many points are in `points`? also, do the values in `Xcart`, `Ycart` change frequently or are they the same from image to image?

Comment: There are 1755*525 points. Values `Xcart` and `Ycart` are the same from image to image, but they do not lie in a regular grid

Comment: I rewrited it using interp2d (this way requires loop which I wrote using cython). It improved the performance a bit, but it is still very slow